# Where on the DC are password's hashes saved?

Tags: domain, password-management, hashing

Like title says, where are the password's hashes from all the computers on the domain saved on the DC?
 And where is that file on the dc's filesystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are stored in %windir%\NTDS\ntds.dit file, but you cannot read them (for security reasons). Quite pretty explanation you can find in [this Technet thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/63e3cf2d-f186-418e-bc85-58bdc1861aae/view-password-hash-in-active-directory).